# Unable to access MacBook Pro as im not the Admin Accountant

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, administrator

My previous employers have gone into liquidation and no longer provide business or services. I have my work MacBook Pro which have not been requested to be returned.
How can I remove the current Admin/Remote User Access to the MacBook? Ive tried resetting the password, but im unable to.
Is there any hardware that would need to be replaced to restore this back to factory settings equivalent and allow me Admin access?? Its a shame for such a lovely device to gather dust...

Comment: It will depend on the precise model of Mac & whether it's tied to an MDM solution. Worst-case scenario, Apple can unlock it if you can get the company to provide you with some sort of proof of ownership.

Comment: Thankyou. The Mac is 2020 model but not sure how I identify if there's a MDM solution. Any way to find out?

Comment: I'm not certain, but there are a lot of folks on here familiar with MDM.